# Merging dataframes by a vector of dataframe names

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge approx 30 dataframes.

I have saved the global environment as a vector, comma separated, as below;

```
df_names <- (df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

Now I am trying to merge all of these dataframes

```
total <- merge(df_names, by = 'ID')
```

But I am getting an error;

```
Error in as.data.frame(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Check out `?mget` to put them in a list

Comment: `mget` + `Reduce` should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comments to an answer, you're probably looking for a combination of `mget` and `Reduce` along with `merge`.

Demo:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = 1:3, var = c("a", "b", "c"))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 3, 4), var = c("A", "B", "X"))
df3 <- data.frame(ID = c(2, 3, 4, 5), var = c("X", "Y", "Z", "A")) 
df4 <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, var = letters[1:5])
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "ID", all = TRUE), mget(paste0("df", 1:4)))
#   ID var.x var.y var.x var.y
# 1  1     a     A  <NA>     a
# 2  2     b  <NA>     X     b
# 3  3     c     B     Y     c
# 4  4  <NA>     X     Z     d
# 5  5  <NA>  <NA>     A     e
# Warning message:
# In merge.data.frame(x, y, by = "ID", all = TRUE) :
#   column names ‘var.x’, ‘var.y’ are duplicated in the result
```

Comment: I try to run this on my dataframe and it just reproduces the dataframe names: I have currently; `df_names <- names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame))))` which gives me the list of df_names. Then I tidy it up by `df_names <- paste(as.character(df_names),collapse=", ",sep="")
` so I have a list of dataframe names such as, `df1, df2, df3, df4` etc. and here I would like to call in `total <- merge(df_names, by = 'PANID')` but I get an error.

Comment: @user113156, why would you paste the names together? Why not just leave it as a vector? Try `Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "ID", all = TRUE), mget(df_names))` *before* you do the `df_names <- paste(as.character(...), ...)`.

Comment: Yes, thanks it worked! but crashed my computer as the df was too big, but it worked! Thanks