# Using the elements of a character vector as the data input name for a function

Tags: r

I have some data sets like these;

```
mydata1_sorted <- data.frame(Col1 = runif(3,1,5),
             Col2 = runif(3,1,5), 
             Col3 = runif(3,1,5))

mydata2_sorted <- data.frame(Col1 = runif(2,1,3),
             Col2 = runif(2,1,3), 
             Col3 = runif(2,1,3))

mydata3_sorted <- data.frame(Col1 = runif(2,1,6),
             Col2 = runif(2,1,6), 
             Col3 = runif(2,1,6))
```

I use `expand.grid` function as below, and it is working fine.

`expand.grid(mydata1_sorted$Col1, mydata2_sorted$Col1, mydata3_sorted$Col1)`

However, for some reasons, I need to apply the very same function wrt the list below.

```
datalist <- list( group1=c("mydata1","mydata2","mydata3"),
                group2 = c("mydata2","mydata3"),
                 group3 = c("mydata1","mydata3"))
```

To do so I wrote the codes below;

```
for(i in 1:length(datalist)) {

   list_sorted <- paste0(datalist[[i]],"_sorted$Col1")

   to_function <-noquote(paste(list_sorted, collapse=','))

   result <- expand.grid(to_function)

   print(result)

}
```

Unfortunately, I haven't achieved to pass the vectors to the `expend.grid` function, since the output gives only the characters inside the `expend.grid`.

I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797285/merging-dataframes-by-a-vector-of-dataframe-names), including `mget` function. And I tried to apply it as below,

```
 mget(paste0("mydata", 1:3,"_sorted$Col1"))
```

But I had this : 
`Error: value for ‘mydata1_sorted$Col1’ not found`

Any solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first create a `z` object which has all the rows needed for each group of the `datalist`. Then we apply `expand.grid` to each matrix. Keep in mynd the `$Col1` has to be outside of the `get()` function.

```
z=lapply(datalist,function(x){lapply(x,function(y) get(paste0(y,"_sorted"))$Col1)})
lapply(z,expand.grid)
$`group1`
       Var1     Var2     Var3
1  2.209588 2.600266 3.693475
2  3.251563 2.600266 3.693475
3  1.412309 2.600266 3.693475
4  2.209588 1.865730 3.693475
5  3.251563 1.865730 3.693475
6  1.412309 1.865730 3.693475
7  2.209588 2.600266 3.718085
8  3.251563 2.600266 3.718085
9  1.412309 2.600266 3.718085
10 2.209588 1.865730 3.718085
11 3.251563 1.865730 3.718085
12 1.412309 1.865730 3.718085

$group2
      Var1     Var2
1 2.600266 3.693475
2 1.865730 3.693475
3 2.600266 3.718085
4 1.865730 3.718085

$group3
      Var1     Var2
1 2.209588 3.693475
2 3.251563 3.693475
3 1.412309 3.693475
4 2.209588 3.718085
5 3.251563 3.718085
6 1.412309 3.718085
```

Comment: Thank you @boski, Codes are working fine and it is also faster than using a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(datalist, ~  mget(str_c(.x, "_sorted"), envir = .GlobalEnv) %>%
          map(pluck, 'Col1')) %>% 
          map(expand.grid)
```